# Use of if condition in MYSQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Does an `IF` condition in the where clause of a MySQL query slow down the execution drastically?

Here is the one sample query:-

```
select * from alert_details_v adv
where (if(day(last_day(now()))<DAY(adv.alert_date),
day(last_day(now())),DAY(adv.alert_date))-adv.alert_trigger_days)<=day(now());
```

Sample data:

```
alert_id  alert_date            alert_trigger_days
==================================================
1         2013-09-14 00:00:00   6
2         2013-09-13 00:00:00   5
```

- `alert_date`: Some user input date
- `alert_trigger_days`: Number of days before the actual date the alert be triggered.

Brief about query logic:-
Here I am trying to find if the last day of the current month is less than the day of the `alert_date` (database column). Whichever day comes before would be considered.

Basically this table is meant for storing alert information. So if the user has chosen 30th of some month and the alert is recurring monthly then for February it would not find the day 30th and hence would not show the record.

**My question** is: does a query with if conditions (as in the sample query above) in where clause slows down the execution of the query drastically or slightly, if there are hundreds of thousands of records in the table?

Comment: Please provide an example of the query with table layouts.  The answer is "sometimes yes, sometimes no".

Comment: This question appears to be "too broad" because there are either too many possible answers.

Comment: Please let me know your thoughts now and also if more information is required. Thanks

Comment: My question is that does a query with if conditions(as in the sample query above) in where clause slows down the execution of the query drastically or slightly, if there are lakh's of records in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may entirely depend upon your table and data. Sometimes it may help in increasing the performance and sometimes it may degrade your performance.

Comment: Please let me know your thoughts now and also if more information is required. Thanks